# What is the difference in Windows and Linux client copy/move commands on Linux hosts?

Tags: linux, windows, network-shares, samba, media-server

With my Linux media server and files shared through Samba on a home network, moving files using a Windows machine takes seconds as though it's telling the server to move file from point A to point B. When using a Linux client (same results on several distros, namely, Raspbian, Fedora, Mint), it takes much longer, as though it's moving it from server to host and back to server. Is this what's happening? Is there a way to transfer the files faster using the Linux client?

Comment: Yes, current versions all around. Windows transfers the files around the server near-instantly. It's the Linux machines that take time. Origin and destination directories are both on the server.

Comment: The sentence that explained the behavior read weird.  Disregard my comment then.

Comment: What client are you using for Samba (i.e. gnome-vfs, gvfs, kio, smbnetfs, smbclient, in-kernel cifs.ko) and _how_ are you performing the move, precisely?

Comment: I'm just guessing, for the most part, but reading about Caja, Nautilus/Files, and Nemo, they all seem to use gvfs and/or gio. I get to the desired file in the file various managers, browsing through "network", the doman, the server, then to each share. I'm going to assume it has something to do with this, because I've now (in Caja) used, from the file menu, "connect to server" and used ssh, which seems to act as desired.

Comment: All of those use gio+gvfs, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's strange at least.

Windows file moving actually didn't move files on the server but updates MFT that's all, but Linux have to copy file to the new place and delete it on the old one instead.
Samba project is using reverse engineered CIFS protocol so far I know.

But if you have Samba server on Linux it can't be the issue.

Can you try to mount CIFS share on Linux and check if file moving still takes much of the time?

Comment: That seems to be exactly what Windows is doing. Adding a server location within Caja over SSH seems to change the behavior. I'm not sure exactly how to mount the share using CIFS, but it seems that the problem lies in the how Caja et al mount SMB network shares by default.